# How did this user offer a bounty on their question?

Tags: support, bounties

How can someone with a reputation of 19 offer a bounty of 100, and thus stop the question being closed?

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/56602/cannot-ssh-nor-nvc-into-my-pi-3-on-the-wifi-network

Comment: They had 119 before offering the bounty?

Comment: ... as a [look at their rep page would readily show](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/34586/profk?tab=reputation&sort=time)

Comment: @rene undeleted now, probably the moderator who did it was not aware of the option to refund a bounty. See the [revisions](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/56602/revisions), the bounty is automatically removed when the question is deleted. Though not sure why the moderator waited for 12 minutes.

Comment: Please don't edit commentry into your question.

Comment: @Milliways no one is deliberately misrepresenting your question or abusing their powers... my edit was a rollback to your original words. What's the problem? A link to another question and nothin else makes little sense

Comment: @Cai I NEVER suggested the user offered a bounty to "stop the question being closed". I said "and thus stop the question being closed" - which is a true statement, implying no malicious intent on the part of the questioner, but reflects badly on me. The question was poor, I wanted to flag it for possible closure - which it since has been.

Comment: @Cai I misread your edit, and apologise. I have got fed up with people editing the post. I find it offensive that anybody thinks they can edit another person's words. I have no problem with formatting edits, or corrections to errors, but I still think anyone who does this should have the integrity to identify themselves.

Comment: I understand your frustration but the fact of the matter is that anyone can edit anyone else's post. No one was intentionally misrepresenting your question or abusing their powers, the misunderstanding comes down to a few ambiguous words. It would have been better to reword clearly your intention than get in to a rollback war

Comment: Cai no point wasting time on trying to edit or help OP here.

Comment: I ran into a similar situation.  User put up a 100 point bounty when they had only ever asked 2 questions with a total of 1 upvote (mine).  I asked myself how they could possibly start a bounty.  When I looked at their reputation page, it became clear.  They spent their association bonus of 100 rep for coming over from another exchange.

Answer (score 6):

They can't. And they didn't. The user must have had enough reputation at the time of starting the bounty.

As you can see now, the question is deleted and the reputation was refunded.

Setting a bounty doesn't mean the question can't be closed at all, moderators can still close those questions. All it needs for you to do is raise a custom flag and explain why it needs to be closed.

Comment: Okay, you are correct!  My mistake -- the issue is that post deletion there was no longer a bounty, and so the option to remove it was gone.  I've corrected the situation and deleted my previous comments here since they are just clutter now.

Comment: Patrick, for some reason I do not understand people keep editing my question to make it as if I said something I did not. I accept that I was wrong, and did not understand the bounty system (on the Raspberry Pi site it is rarely used, and AFAIK has never produced an answer that wassn't already available). I can't delete my question, and stop further abuse because of your answer.